# Lua - string.find(x, "a - b c") gives nil value

Tags: string, lua

I use:

```
x = "Testing a - b c Test"
y = string.find(x, "a - b c")
print(y)
```

And this prints nil. But why? There is a "a - b c" string inside of x. If I use `y = string.find(x, "b c")` then it prints `13` which is correct but I HAVE to find `a - b c`...

Comment: Maybe ''-'' is a special character and needs a ''\'' before it?

Comment: It's not. Tried it though and it gives an error.

Comment: According to my google search,  it has something to do with repetitions in Lua. I'm not familiar with the language though...

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov Unlike most regexes, Lua uses %'s, not \'s, but you are right: "-" is a non-greedy search character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[string.find](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find) second argument is regex pattern, not a plain string. To search for literal string, use this code:

```
y = string.find(x, "a - b c", 1, true)
```